# To print a div with the css style

Tags: javascript

I made a script to print just a div, but when I see the preview, it doesn't "format" the page using the CSS added.

HTML Part:

```
<center>Do not print this</center>              
<div>Hi mom!</div>
<center>Print this</center>
<div id="content" class="print">Hi dad!</div>
            <input type='button' value='Print' onClick='Print()' />
```

JS part

```
function Print(){
     var corpo = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

     var a = window.open('','','width=640,height=480');
     a.document.open("text/html");
     a.document.write("<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./style.css\"></head><body><div class=\"print\">");
     a.document.write(corpo);
     a.document.write("</div></body></html>");
     a.document.close();
     a.print(); 
}
```

A live version: https://codepen.io/Pop1111/pen/Vwabbzd

It looks like it load the css only AFTER.

Any tips?

Comment: In codepen styles are used inline. Check page in DevTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will create invalid HTML

Try

```js
function Print() {
  var corpo = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
  const html = [];
  html.push('<html><head>');
  // assuming the first stylesheet on the parent page - use a different selector if not
  // or use +location.protocol+'//'+location.host+'/style.css">'
  html.push('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + document.querySelector("link[rel=stylesheet]").href + '">');
  html.push('</head><body onload="window.focus(); window.print()"><div>');
  html.push(corpo);
  html.push('</div></body></html>');
  console.log(html)
  /*  this will not work in the snippet - uncomment on your server
  var a = window.open('', '', 'width=640,height=480');
  a.document.open("text/html");
  a.document.write(html.join(""));
  a.document.close();
  */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <center>Do not print this</center>
  <div>Hi mom!</div>
  <center>Print this</center>
  <div id="content" class="print">Hi dad!</div>
  <input type='button' value='Print' onClick='Print()' />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is the same.

Comment: it doesn't work. in the head I see <link rel="stylesheet" href="undefined">

Comment: now it is exacty as my first version. It doesn't "format" the page using the CSS added IN A FIRST MOMENT. I have to close the Print Window, open it again and then it works. Try it locally

Comment: Try removing `a.print()` and use `html.push('</head><body onload="print()"><div>');`

Comment: but in this way it doesn't open the Print window...

Answer (score 0):

Your new document is unsaved, so does not have your expected path, so the relative reference of the CSS file is not finding the CSS.

To get this to work as expected, you would need to change the CSS reference to absolute reference, or add code to save the new HTML file first.

Is this just how you have tested it, or will your production version function like this as well? (New file, not saved, then print).

You could always inject the actual CSS itself into the head of the new document between style tags, instead of just a reference to the CSS file. Try that.